# Why is $\boldsymbol{\mathrm{\tau}} = \boldsymbol{\mathrm{\omega}} \times \boldsymbol{\mathrm{L}}$ in Larmor precession?

Tags: electromagnetism, classical-mechanics, rotational-kinematics, rigid-body-dynamics

I saw this equation in a paper while ago. I remember that the paper was on Larmor precession; i.e.,
$$\boldsymbol{\mathrm{\omega}}_{\text{}} = \frac{q\boldsymbol{\mathrm{B}} }{2m}$$
How is the formula equating the torque $\boldsymbol{\mathrm{\tau}} $ with the cross product of Larmor frequency and angular momentum derived?

Comment: Have you just checked https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larmor_precession

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relation
\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol{\tau} = \boldsymbol{\omega} \times \boldsymbol{L}
\end{equation}
is a result of vector calculus independent of the phenomenon of Larmor precession.

It follows from the formula of the time derivative of a vector with constant modulus.

Assume that we have a vector $\boldsymbol{a}=a\,\boldsymbol{\hat{a}}(t)$, where $a$ is its constant modulus and $\boldsymbol{\hat{a}}(t)$ is the unit vector, whose direction depends on time. Let's take the time derivative
\begin{equation}
\frac{\mathrm{d}\boldsymbol{a}}{\mathrm{d}t} = \underbrace{\frac{\mathrm{d}a}{\mathrm{d}t}}_0\boldsymbol{\hat{a}} + a\frac{\mathrm{d}\boldsymbol{\hat{a}}}{\mathrm{d}t}
\end{equation}
The first term is zero because we assumed that the modulus of the vector is constant.
The second term is slightly more difficult to treat.
Consider the image below (interpret $\vec{a}$ as unit vectors).

[image]

As the derivative can be considered as
\begin{equation}
\frac{\mathrm{d}\boldsymbol{\hat{a}}}{\mathrm{d}t} = \lim_{\Delta t \to0}\frac{\Delta \boldsymbol{\hat{a}}}{\Delta t}
\end{equation}
we can see that if $\Delta t$ becomes very small, also the angle $\Delta\phi\to0$, and hence $\Delta \boldsymbol{\hat{a}}$ tends to be orthogonal to $\boldsymbol{\hat{a}}$. As the derivative must have the same direction as $\Delta \boldsymbol{\hat{a}}$, we conclude
\begin{equation}
\frac{\mathrm{d}\boldsymbol{\hat{a}}}{\mathrm{d}t} \parallel \Delta \boldsymbol{\hat{a}} \,\bot\, \boldsymbol{\hat{a}}
\end{equation}
Let's compute the modulus now.
\begin{equation}
\left| \frac{\mathrm{d}\boldsymbol{\hat{a}}}{\mathrm{d}t}\right| = 2\lim_{\Delta t\to0}\left|\frac{\Delta \boldsymbol{\hat{a}}}{\Delta t} \right|= \lim_{\Delta t\to0}\frac{\left|\Delta \boldsymbol{\hat{a}}\right|}{\Delta t} 
\end{equation}
From the figure, we can easily see that $|\Delta \boldsymbol{\hat{a}}| = 2 |\boldsymbol{\hat{a}}| \sin(\Delta\phi / 2) =2 \sin(\Delta\phi / 2)  $, because the unit vectors have modulus $1$. Hence the previous equation becomes
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\left| \frac{\mathrm{d}\boldsymbol{\hat{a}}}{\mathrm{d}t}\right| &=\lim_{\Delta t\to0, \Delta \phi \to 0}\frac{2 \sin(\Delta\phi / 2)}{\Delta t} \\
&= \lim_{\Delta t\to0, \Delta \phi \to 0}2\frac{  \sin(\Delta\phi / 2)}{\Delta\phi / 2}\frac{\Delta\phi / 2}{\Delta t}\\
&=\lim_{\Delta \phi \to 0}\frac{\sin(\Delta\phi / 2)}{\Delta\phi / 2}\lim_{\Delta t \to 0}\frac{\Delta\phi}{\Delta t}\\
& = 1 \cdot \frac{\mathrm{d}\phi}{\mathrm{d}t}\\
&=\omega
\end{split}
\end{equation}
where in the last line we introduced the angular velocity.

Putting all together we have that the derivative $\frac{\mathrm{d}\boldsymbol{\hat{a}}}{\mathrm{d}t}$ is orthogonal to $\boldsymbol{\hat{a}}$ and has modulus $\omega$. We can cleverly use the vector product to combine these 2 properties in one equation.
\begin{equation}
\frac{\mathrm{d}\boldsymbol{\hat{a}}}{\mathrm{d}t} = \boldsymbol{\omega}\times \boldsymbol{\hat{a}}
\end{equation}

Finally,
\begin{equation}
\frac{\mathrm{d}\boldsymbol{a}}{\mathrm{d}t} = \underbrace{\frac{\mathrm{d}a}{\mathrm{d}t}}_0\boldsymbol{\hat{a}} + a\frac{\mathrm{d}\boldsymbol{\hat{a}}}{\mathrm{d}t} = a\boldsymbol{\omega}\times \boldsymbol{\hat{a}} = \boldsymbol{\omega}\times \boldsymbol{a}\qquad\mbox{if}\qquad|\boldsymbol a | = \mbox{const.}
\end{equation}
which is the **Poisson formula**.

### In your case

As the torque is the time derivative of the angular momentum and the modulus of the angular momentum is constant, from the Poisson formula you have that

\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol{\tau} =\frac{\mathrm{d}\boldsymbol{L}}{\mathrm{d}t}= \boldsymbol{\omega} \times \boldsymbol{L}
\end{equation}

Comment: Thank you this was a great answer to my question!

Comment: @innating If my post helped you feel free to accept it as the right answer. I can provide more detail if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

[From Wikipedia:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larmor_precession)

the torque by a magnetic field induced on a magnetic moment is:
$$\vec{\tau}=\gamma \vec{L}\times\vec{B}$$

where $\vec{L}$ is the angular momentum, $\gamma=-\frac{eg}{2m}$ is the gyromagnetic ratio and $\vec{B}$ is the magnetic field.

The Larmor Frequency can be written in terms of the gyromagnetic ratio as follows:
$$\omega=-\gamma B$$

therefore:
$$\vec{\tau}=\gamma \vec{L}\times\vec{B}=-\gamma\vec{B}\times\vec{L}=\vec{\omega}\times\vec{L}$$